# Angular $state.go

Tags: angularjs, state

In my template, i have the following code : `<a ng-click="countryDetail(country.id)" style="cursor:pointer">{{country.name}}</a>`

In my ng-controller i have this code to retrieve the data from the country table in my DB :

```
 $scope.countryDetail= function (id) {
        if (!id) return;
        Country.countryDetail(id)
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.loadedCountry = Country.loadedCountry ;
             console.log($scope.loadedCountry);
            $state.go('country.detail', { 'countryId': id });
        });
    };

My service :

  countryService.countryDetail = function (id) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        return $http.get(countryUrl + "detail/" + id)
             .success(function (data) {
                 deferred.resolve(
                      countryService.loadedCountry = data);
             })
        .error(function (error) {
            deferred.reject(error);
        })
        return deferred.promise;
    }
```

state in my app.js

```
.state('country.detail', {
               url: '^/country/detail/{countryId:[0-9]{1,6}}',
               templateUrl: 'app/country/countryDetail.html',
               controller: 'countryCtrl'
           })
```

When i click the country name link, the console shows the country object with the good values but the country.detail template has a null Country object. When i added `$scope.countryDetail()` after my function, the data are displayed in the detail template but there's 2 calls in the server !! So how can use only one call without calling `$scope.countryDetail()` again ?. Thanks

Comment: Seems like you are making the `$http` request in the wrong controller. Consider making it in `resolve` of `country.detail` or from the `country.detail` controller

Comment: The $http request is in my service. See my first question, i added an update

Comment: Right but you don't want to make that request before you change routes. you are ending up with the data in wrong controller scope

Comment: Unrelated, but your service creates its own promise, and then it returns the one created by `$http`. You don't need to create your own promise...

Comment: What's the right solution then ? cause i'm new with angular, and i followed a tutorial online and i think it was a good approach to separate the service and the controller

Comment: Has nothing to do with separation of service/controller,  which is indeed good practice, but with making the request in wrong controller. Can use `$stateParams` to get the id in `detail` route and make request there so the data ends up in controller that needs it

Comment: I'm only using one controller. The same used for $state.go. See my updated question. I think if you give me an example that will help.

Comment: Even if you use the same controller function for both states (and you probably shouldn't), changing the state will create a new scope and a new controller instance using that scope.

Comment: All that answers seems to be good ! but i still don't have the right answer yet that will solve my problem !

Comment: A Plunker or an example here will help  ! thanks

Comment: Good idea. Build one with what you got so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK. Let me explain what you're doing:

- click on a link to display a country
- load the country and store it in the scope
- go to another state

That can't work, because when you go to another state, the scope of the current controller goes away: a new scope is created, and a new controller is instantiated.

So, what you must do instead is

- click on a link to display a country
- go to another state which is configured to use another controller: CountryDetailController
- in the CountryDetailController, get the country detail from the server and store it in the scope

Then it will work: the country detail will be stored in the correct scope, and the view of the new state will display it.

Another option: use the `resolve` parameter of the state configuration (it's explained in the documentation, so that the following happens:

- click on a link to display a country
- go to another state which is configured to use another controller: CountryDetailController
- the ui router calls the resolve function that returns a promise of country detail. It waits until the country is available
- when the country is available, the router instantiates CountryDetailController and injects the country itself
- in the CountryDetailController, get the injected country detail from the function arguments and store it in the scope

Comment: Ah that's better :) i will try this and let you know, thanks you !

Comment: The first option works for me. I wanted to avoid the use of another controller but i think i have no choice. Thank you sir.